# Flutter AdMob: how do I track Interstitial Ad payment amount?

Tags: flutter, dart, admob

I am implementing AdMob into my Flutter application, and I have interstitial ads showing up correctly in Test Mode. I would now like to determine how much money a particular ad has made, and that doesn't seem to be working.

The solution I have tried to make that happen is using the `onPaidEvent` function (please let me know if this is incorrect), so in the `onAdLoaded` function, I currently have the following code:

```
ad.onPaidEvent = (Ad ad, double valueMicros, PrecisionType precision, String currencyCode) {
  double cents = valueMicros * 10000;
  print(cents);
} as OnPaidEventCallback;
```

When I include this code, the app never gets to the call to `InterstitialAd.load`, but without it, it gets past the `InterstitialAd.load` and displays the ad properly (on both Android and iOS).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am now wondering how to properly deal with the parameters provided, and the details in the documentation seem unclear. What resources can I look to for this? I'm specifically wondering about the nature of `valueMicros`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not actually with the callback, but rather my own code: I was using the posted code snippet inside of a class that was also called `Ad`, which was ambiguous and therefore causing casting problems.

Comment: can you post the solution?

Comment: What exactly do you want the solution for? I can post my code for the whole Ad implementation, but that might be beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: i need solution for tracking ads payment amount please.

Comment: You just need to set `onPaidEvent` for the ad you're tracking, and put your specific tracking functionality into that function. Does that make sense? Maybe you could ask a question with what you have so far.